# Order confirmation emails not sending

Tags: magento2, email, order-email, magento-2.2.5

Once I place an order, confirmation email is not sent.

In the backend (Sales -> Orders), the order says that "The order confirmation email is not sent".

If I click "Send Email", it still doesn't send.

Other mail functionality works (e.g. Forgot Password). Emails are configured under Stores -> Configuration -> Sales -> Sales Emails. Under Advanced -> System, my Mail Sending Settings are as so:

[image]

Cron job is setup and running four times every hour, as so:

[image]

`system.log`: https://pastebin.com/X2Vm0trx

`update.cron.log`:

```
Could not open input file: /home/[user]/public_html/update/cron.php
Could not open input file: /home/[user]/public_html/update/cron.php
Could not open input file: /home/[user]/public_html/update/cron.php
Could not open input file: /home/[user]/public_html/update/cron.php
Could not open input file: /home/[user]/public_html/update/cron.php
...
```

`update.log`:

```
[2018-09-02 22:14:02] setup-cron.ERROR: Could not locate magento/magento2-base/composer.json file. [] []
```

I suspect it's from a conflict with one of my installed extensions, given the error in my system.log:

```
[2018-09-02 23:52:02] main.ERROR: Notice: Undefined property: MageArray\OrderAttachments\Model\Order\Email\SenderBuilder::$messageManager in /home/[user]/public_html/app/code/MageArray/OrderAttachments/Model/Order/Email/SenderBuilder.php on line 75 [] []
```

But there are also those other errors that are present, and I don't know if those errors are the ones causing the order confirmation emails to not be sent.

Comment: New to Magento. Can anyone please tell me how do you detect which third-party extension creating the conflict?

Comment: List all  extensions which are overriding sales module, or are having any feature/functionality related to orders, and then check by disabling them one by one

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/137016)

Comment: @Bandini Exactly what @Piyush said, but also scan the logs for errors. Logs located under `var/log/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirmed, the external module was causing the issue.

I disabled the module and the order confirmation email came through.

Comment: Which modules you disabled?

Comment: @NimeshPatel the external module that had functionality relating to orders. It directly interfered with the email functionality, preventing emails from being sent. Check all of your external modules to see if any deal with order or email functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution for Magento 2.2.7. In my issue, other emails are working well but only transactional email are not working. Please review below link for transactional emails are not working solution.
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/14952#issuecomment-447684074